# Reevaluate a computed function every x seconds in KnockoutJS

Tags: knockout.js

Can I execute the computed function say every 1000 ms to get a new timespan value every 1000 ms displayed in my UI ?

```
self.timespan = ko.computed(function() {
        return self.orderTime() + " " + new Date();
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Wrap your `new Date()` in a timer observable, and update it every 1000 ms using [`setInterval`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window.setInterval), for example like this:

```
function myViewModel() {
    var self = this;

    self.orderTime = ko.observable(new Date(2013,1,1,12,0,0));
    self.timer = ko.observable(new Date());

    self.timespan = ko.computed(function() {
        return self.orderTime() + " " + self.timer();
    });    

    window.setInterval(function() { self.timer(new Date()); }, 1000);
}

ko.applyBindings(new myViewModel());
```

If you want you could also always make the `timer` observable private to the ViewModel's scope, depending on whether you want to expose it directly or not.

See [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jeroenheijmans/X9jek/) for a demo.

Comment: ok I already use the setInterval to execute the new DAte creation every x seconds. I rather thought of a solution knockout related. But maybe yours is more elegant or maybe less code I have to check that out , thanks!