# Magento2 knockoutjs, how can I update customer name in header every second from custom module?

Tags: knockout.js, magento2

```
define(['uiComponent', 'ko', 'Magento_Customer/js/customer-data'], function (Component, ko, customerData) {
    "use strict";

    return Component.extend({
        initialize: function () {
            var self = this;
            this._super();
            self.customer = customerData.get('customer');
            self.customer().fullname = ko.observable(self.customer().fullname);
            window.setInterval(function () {
                var selectFruit = ["Apple", "Orange", "Banana", "Cherry"];
                self.customer().fullname = selectFruit[Math.floor(Math.random() * 4)];
                console.log(self.customer().fullname);
            }, 500);
        }
    });
});
```

I tried to reproduce [Reevaluate a computed function every x seconds in KnockoutJS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16997638/reevaluate-a-computed-function-every-x-seconds-in-knockoutjs) this in m2 but it doesn't work. The data which I get from console.log(self.customer().fullname) - is working well. But the customer name from header still wasn't changed.

If I did like this:

```
self.customer().fullname = ko.observable('random text');
```

- It's working well. But I want to change this value every second

Any minds about it ?

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem this way:

```
self.customer({fullname: 'something'});
```

Don't know, but it works. Maybe for somebody will be useful!